# awk adding color code to text

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

```
awk -F: '{ printf  "%-3s %-2s","\n" $1 $2; }'
```

How do i add in color code? '\e[1;32m'

I try adding in to printf, it give me output of the string instead of color code..

```
'\e[1;32m' .......
```

Comment: Does that color code work with a normal `echo`?

Answer (score 21):

`\033[?m` properly quoted gives colour:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "\033[34msomething in colour\033[0m";}'
```

notice how one needs to unescape `$1` below:

```
echo something | awk '{ print "\033[34m"$1" in colour \033[0m";}'
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this example:

```
echo "line 1
line 2" | awk '/line/ {print "\033[32m" $1 "\033[31m" $2 }'
```

[image]

Color is given by `"\033[32m"`

For Colors:

```
30 - black   34 - blue          
   31 - red     35 - magenta       
   32 - green   36 - cyan          
   33 - yellow  37 - white
```

Answer (score 9):

`awk` doesn't recognize '\e' as a code for the escape character. Here's a workaround (something more elegant may exist):

```
# Decimal 27 is the ASCII codepoint for the escape character
awk '{ printf "%c[1;32m foo\n", 27 }' <<<foo
```

Comment: how about.. using \033 instead of \e

Comment: I always forget about the octal escapes.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps anyone looking for an answer!

As you can see, the functions and various initialization makes it possible to write quite a simple print line as below.

```
print colour("Red")$1colour("Blue")$0colour("None");
```

For the `colour` function, you may either pass in the integer value of colour or the name. It takes params in the below formats.

```
colour( <attribute> , <background-colour> , <foreground-colour> )
colour( <background-colour> , <foreground-colour> )
colour( <foreground-colour> )
```

You can selectively give the required params.

```
function isnumeric(x)
{
    return ( x == x+0 );
}

function name_to_number(name, predefined)
{
    if (isnumeric(name))
        return name;

    if (name in predefined)
        return predefined[name];

    return name;
}

function colour(v1, v2, v3)
{
    if (v3 == "" && v2 == "" && v1 == "")
        return;

    if (v3 == "" && v2 == "")
        return sprintf("%c[%dm", 27, name_to_number(v1, fgcolours));
    else if (v3 == "")
        return sprintf("%c[%d;%dm", 27, name_to_number(v1, bgcolours), name_to_number(v2, fgcolours));
    else
        return sprintf("%c[%d;%d;%dm", 27, name_to_number(v1, attributes), name_to_number(v2, bgcolours), name_to_number(v3, fgcolours));
}

BEGIN {
    # hack to use attributes for just "None"
    fgcolours["None"] = 0;

    fgcolours["Black"] = 30;
    fgcolours["Red"] = 31;
    fgcolours["Green"] = 32;
    fgcolours["Yellow"] = 33;
    fgcolours["Blue"] = 34;
    fgcolours["Magenta"] = 35;
    fgcolours["Cyan"] = 36;
    fgcolours["White"] = 37;

    bgcolours["Black"] = 40;
    bgcolours["Red"] = 41;
    bgcolours["Green"] = 42;
    bgcolours["Yellow"] = 43;
    bgcolours["Blue"] = 44;
    bgcolours["Magenta"] = 45;
    bgcolours["Cyan"] = 46;
    bgcolours["White"] = 47;

    attributes["None"] = 0;
    attributes["Bold"] = 1;
    attributes["Underscore"] = 4;
    attributes["Blink"] = 5;
    attributes["ReverseVideo"] = 7;
    attributes["Concealed"] = 8;
}

{
    print colour("Red")$1colour("Blue")$0colour("None");
}
```

Comment: Extremely underrated comment. If this were reddit, I'd give you an award. I'm going to enjoy this a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print "^[[1;33mYELLOW"}'
```

would print string YELLOW in yellow (color)

**NOTE** 
the first `^[` you have to type `ctrl-v` then `ESC`

I would add a screen shot to show.

[image]

the above screenshot showed it worked under zsh and bash.

Answer (score -2):

```
BDF()
{
#awk 'BEGIN{ print "\033[34msomething in colour\033[0m";}'
#bdf $spool $data $sysout ~ /home/fnsonlh  |grep -v avail| awk '{print $5" "$4"        "}' | tail -n +2 |tr -d "\012"
bdf $spool $data $sysout ~ /home/fnsonlh  |grep -v avail| awk '{if($4 > 89)
 {
   print "\033[0;31m"$5" "$4"\033[0m      "
  }
 else
 {
  print "\033[0;32m"$5" "$4"\033[0m      "
 }}' |tail -n +2 |tr -d "\012"
#"\012 is new line caracter"
echo
#/usr/bin/w -u
uptime
}
#nishant.chawre@gmail.com
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon. Please edit your answer to include a description of what the code is doing and how it answers the question.

Answer (score -2):

Define two variables or those that you need

Example:

```
GREENB='\033[0;41m'    #Green Background (Color verde de fondo)
GREEN='\033[0;32m'     #Green Text (Color verde en el texto
REDB='\033[0;41m'      #Red Background (Color rojo de fondo)
RED='\033[0;31m'       #Red text (Color rojo en el texto)
NORMALB='\033[0;49m'   #Default background (Color por defecto de fondo)
NORMAL='\033[0m'       #Default foreground (Color por defecto del texto)
```

awk code : 
`echo "This is a test" | awk -vRojo=${RED} -v NC=${NORMAL} '{print Rojo $1, $2, NC $3, $4}'`

---

#### Color code explanation

**`\e[${ATTRIBUTE};${BACKGROUND_COLOR};${FOREGROUND_COLOR}m`**

Where:

- **`\e`**: `<Esc>` character (can be `\e`, `\033`,`\x1B`)
- **`${ATTRIBUTE}`**: Defines the **style** of the text (*Normal*, *Bold/Bright*, *Dim*, *Underlined*, *Blink*, *Reverse*, *Hidden*). 0 is Normal;
- **`${BACKGROUND_COLOR}`**: Defines the **background** color;
- **`${FOREGROUND_COLOR}`**: Defines the **foreground** color;

---

#### More Info

More colors and info on Bash colors 
[here](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Comment: `GREENB = "\ 033 [0; 41m"` won't ever work because the assignment operator in bash MUSTN'T have whitespaces between variable name and variable value... So the correct syntax is `GREENB="`... Also, all those whitespaces inside of the variable value will make awk fail with error `awk: fatal: cannot open file \`[0;' for reading (No such file or directory)` so they MUST be REMOVED... I get it that you did it to make it more readable and easier to unerstand but its syntax is totally wrong... Corrected