# Use tput colors with awk

Tags: awk

How can I specify colours with tput numbers in an awk file?  Have not found enough information to set up colour variables like I can do with bash.

Have done the following, but the strategy is not working.

```bash
  awk 'BEGIN {
         sgr=system("tput sgr0")
         wht=system("tput bold; tput setaf 15")
         blu=system("tput bold; tput setaf 39")
       }
       /Code:$/ { kl=1 ; next }
       !NF { kl=0 }
       kl { printf("%s%s%s\n", blu, $0, sgr) }
       !kl { printf("%s%s%s\n", wht, $0, sgr) }
      ' <<< "$@"
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/735162/133219. Please don't multi-post, especially after you have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already [a very nice answer with your another user here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735162/colouring-code-parts-of-multiline-variable-in-awk) from Ed Morton.

In a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

Using `sgr=system()`, you assign `sgr` with the return code `0` of the `tput` command. Not the good way to achieve what you need.

Declaring `tput` commands internally as requested:

```
awk '
    function printblue(text) {
        cmd="tput bold; tput setaf 39; echo \047"text"\047; tput sgr0"
        system(cmd)
    }
    BEGIN{
        printblue("foobar")
    }
'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       system("tput setaf 4")
       printf("%s\n", "foobar")
       system("tput sgr0")
     }
'
```

or with ANSI sequence:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "\033[34msomething in blue\033[0m";}'
```

Comment: I am asking something different.  I do not want to pass the tput results as arguments.  I want to define them internally.

Comment: Would you know why my implementation fails?

Comment: Check my last solution, it works. You command doesn't work because it output the return code of the system() call

Comment: Here is a TLDP link [Colours and Cursor Movement With tput](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x405.html) -- you can use ANSI escapes for 256-color codes, e.g. `\e[38;39mThe Text\e[0m`

Comment: OP want to use `tput`

Comment: Yep, the link is `tput` the ANSI escapes were my additions.

Comment: How does `blu=system("tput bold; tput setaf 39")` not return the colour code?  Because I plan to utilise many colours, can I avoid defining a function for each colour ?

Comment: I cannot see how your solutions address the implementation I have shown.  I am passing a multiline variable through the redirect operator.  I want the ability to print with different colours by matching lines (e.g. for `Code`:so that subsequent lines are printed in blue.)

Comment: Is there a way to return the codes returned by tput to a colour variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482101/awk-adding-color-code-to-text

Comment: See my edited post with ANSI sequence

Comment: @Goncho regarding [How does blu=system("tput bold; tput setaf 39") not return the colour code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75425479/use-tput-colors-with-awk#comment133085033_75425545) - read the awk man page for `system()`, e.g. at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#I_002fO-Functions where it says `Return command’s exit status` - note "exit status", not "output". You've already been shown how to get a command's output in the answers to your questions [on stackechange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/559749/gibran) and it doesn't involve calling `system()`.